# How do I display any marks that are set on the current line?

Tags: mark

I usually jump to next mark in file using `]'` and `['` commands. But I am not able to find a way to discover whether there are any marks set on current line.

Comment: You could use `m'`.

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear. I want to know which mark is set on the current line. Is there a command through which Vim will display mark set on the current line?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to make marks **visible** in vim proper.

If it is however enough to just list them you can issue the `:marks` *normal*-mode command, which will give you a list of all marks in the current buffer and all global marks (the one with capitalized letters).

Additionally there is a plugin called *showmarks* that will do the job. It displays a column left to the linenumbers-column which will contain the names of the marks on a specific line. This includes global marks.

A few versions of this plugin exist, i've found that Jacques Bodin-Hullin's version is the only one that seems to work without problems in any current version of vim (greater or equal than 7.4). It is located on github: [jacquesbh/vim-showmarks](https://github.com/jacquesbh/vim-showmarks).

If you are using [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim) as your plugin manager you can register it with the following line in your *.vimrc*, after doing a `:PluginInstall jacquesbh/vim-showmarks`.

```
call vundle#begin()
" ... other plugins
Plugin 'jacquesbh/vim-showmarks'
call vundle#end()
```

After you've installed showmarks you can make the marks visible with `:DoShowMarks` and hide them again with `:NoShowMarks` - an `!` at the end will execute the command for all buffers.

Comment: Why Vim out of the box do now show marks? Why we need a plugin for that?